# VS Code sync not working: 'Request failed' error message in logs

Tags: visual-studio-code, synchronization

When I trying to sync my setting, extensions etc from new os (Ubuntu) I have error message
`Error while turning on Settings Sync. Please check logs for more details.`

I'm trying sync without setting and keyboard shortcuts - doesn't work.

In log i have a message:

```
2023-05-27 23:48:25.882 [info] Sync started.
2023-05-27 23:48:25.975 [info] Request failed https://vscode-sync.trafficmanager.net/v1/manifest
```

I am logged into github and added my email and username is global config.